# Altering The Depth of a Kitchen Cabinet

Tags: cabinets, carpentry

The cabinets in our kitchen were installed just prior to us moving into the house.  The cabinet above the fridge is deeper than the other cabinets so that it protrudes over the fridge.  This would be fine if they had also used an end panel to enclose the fridge.  Installing an end panel is not an option as the counter top and backsplash would not allow it to lay flush.

So, I want to either alter the depth of the cabinet to be flush with the other cabinets or simply replace the cabinet.  Considering that a new cabinet would be in the $150 price range, would it even be worth it to try to alter the existing one?

Would I need to disassemble the whole cabinet and cut the boards individually or would it be possible to use a sawzall or something else to shallow out the cabinet before reassembling the back panel.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference in depth?

Comment: The wall cabinet over the fridge is 24" deep.  All other wall cabinets are 12" deep.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't have that depth to allow a person to reach it easily?  The fridge would get in the way of a 12" cabinet for the average person.

Comment: I'm sure they did.  However, a panel is typically used on the side to give the fridge a "built in" look and to help with the overall aesthetics.   Without the panel, it just looks strange.  I would rather just have them all flush as we don't use that cabinet much anyway.

Comment: Post a pic before you do anything with this.  I have this situation in my kitchen and just removed cabinet but every situation is a little different.

Comment: Adding a picture to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would honestly cut the back off that cabinet.  Recreate the backing on it and hang it up again so it is flush with the others.  That is the easiest way and will look the best.

Procedure:

- remove doors
- remove cabinet from wall - unscrew
- carefully measure depth of other cabinets and scribe that depth around the entire perimeter of cabinet in question
- cutout piece with circular saw - dremel might help too
- carefully removing backing pieces from cut part
- recreate backing to ensure integrity of hang (take a photo so you do it right) - this is probably the only difficult step but remember you can make mistakes because not much is showing
- screw back on wall - might need to shim it so it is perfect with current cabinets
- put doors back on

Comment: Just to confirm, you don't feel as thought the whole cabinet would need to be disassembled.  Correct?

Comment: Added outline for you.